# On the relationship of Hopf-algebras and (co)Operads

Tags: algebraic-topology, reference-request, homotopy-theory, intuition, operads

In the paper [Axiomatic Homotopy Theory for Operads](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0206094) Berger and Moerdijk construct a cooperad out of a commutative [bimonoid](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/bimonoid) (I have no idea, why they call the latter a Hopf-object, since in the whole paper no antipode is mentioned). It should be possible to produce an operad out of a cocommutative bimonoid as well, hence both an operad and a cooperad out of a bicommutative bimonoid.

Let me briefly sketch their construction: Given a bimonoid $B$, the cooperad is given by the symmetric sequence $(B^{\otimes n})_n$ with unit map given by the unit $\Bbb{1}\rightarrow B$ of $B$ and structure maps given by the composite
$$\begin{array}{c}
B^{\otimes n_1+...+n_k}\\
\downarrow_\Delta\\
(B^{\otimes n_1}\otimes ... \otimes B^{\otimes n_k}) \otimes (B^{\otimes n_1}\otimes ... \otimes B^{\otimes n_k})\\
\downarrow_{(m\otimes...\otimes m)\otimes id}\\
B^{k}\otimes B^{\otimes n_1}\otimes ... \otimes B^{\otimes n_k}
\end{array}$$
where $\Delta$ is the diagonal/comultiplication of the comonoid $B^{\otimes n_1+...+n_k}$ and $m$ denotes the respective multiplications $B^{\otimes n_i} \rightarrow B$.

I would like to know, whether this is some kind of standard construction. I was unable to find anything about it on the internet and feel like I don't really have a good motivation for the construction.

Without thinking about it, I would have guessed that monoids give rise to monads, hence to operads, while comonoids give rise to comonads, hence cooperads. But Berger&Moerdijk's construction crucially uses *both* the multiplication and comultiplication of the bimonoid to define the cooperad, using the commutativity of the multiplication to verify the equivariance of the cocomposition...

> Why does it make sense to consider this specific cooperad associated to a commutative bimonoid? What does it encode?

If anyone has an opinion or reference about it, please let me know. Regardless, thank you for your time.